# how to send username and password in a spring WebServiceTemplate spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap

I'm creating a client in Spring to access a webservice, but for this webservice I have to send username and password. How to pass username and password using spring wstemplate

When I call the webservice I get the error below:

org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Policy Falsified
at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I created a spring project and used wsimport to create classes from wsdl files. Then I created this service class that the endpoint consumes. It works fine but I get an error Policy Falsified. When I test SOAP using SOAPUI putting basic authentication works. I need to pass this user in password also in my Java project.